# Add curly hair/texture on Bezier Curve mesh

Tags: particles, unity, hair

Currently, I've created something close to dreadlocks. I want to add some texture(image) or hair particles to recreate the fuzziness of real dreadlocks. Can you point me out to some tutorials on how to achieve this?

This is what I got (as you can see, the BezierCurve mesh is really polished for what I am searching for):

[image]

Note: I want to use the character in Unity so I want the solution to work with Unity (not sure if hair particles can be exported or not). Thank you for your time. (I don't mind to self-study but I need the right direction)

Comment: Blender's hair particles don't work in game engines to my knowledge. You have to convert them to mesh. But this can drastically increase the poly count. Hair cards (transparent images with hair strands) work well for game engines but I am not sure if this is the right method for dreadlocks.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I'm not sure I will go with this approach. I will re-create all dreadlocks and apply texture on the first one and just duplicate them.